# How to hide console window in QxtApplication

Tags: c++, qt, libqxt

I am trying to make gui Qxt Application, but when launches it creates a console window. I don't need console window, how can I hide it?

I'm using mingw gcc4.4 qt4.8 libqxt-0.6.2

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui network testlib

CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = yascreens
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    application.cpp \
    configwidget.cpp \
    network.cpp \
    imageselectwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    application.h \
    configwidget.h \
    network.h \
    defines.h \
    imageselectwidget.h

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

FORMS += \
    config.ui
```

Full sources [here](https://github.com/bakwc/yascreens) (github).

Comment: did you try adding in your pro file `CONFIG -= console` ?

Comment: Yep, but still showing console window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was usting QTest and testlib in pro file. Just don't use QTest :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a partitial solution (console window appears for a moment and then hides). You should modify your main.cpp file like:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
    #include <windows.h>
    HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindow(void);     // For hiding console in windows
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);               // For hiding console in windows
    #endif

    // Your application code here
    // ...
}
```